# Why are results rounding down ? (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner trying to make a very basic calculator.
I have a problem with division, though;
For some reasons, the result is always rounded down not matter what:

````
Console.WriteLine("First Argument ?");
int Arg1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Second argument ?");```
int Arg2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
float OpDiv = Arg1 / Arg2;
Console.WriteLine($"The result is {OpDiv}");
````

For example here, 11 / 3 returns 3, instead of 3.66666666...
What have I done wrong ???

Comment: If you divide two integers, you get an integer. If you then convert that integer into a float, you're still gonna get an integer. You need to convert to float _before_ you divide.

Comment: thanks mate  :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
        Console.WriteLine("First Argument ?");
        int Arg1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Second argument ?");
        int Arg2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        float OpDiv = (float)Arg1 / Arg2;
        Console.WriteLine($"The result is {OpDiv}");
```